# what is the function of "have" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence-patterns

I have a problem to recognize this sentence "I have it cuts every weeks".
So, what's the function of "have", and also the name of grammar(if any) or any sentence pattern for similar sentence, and what's the meaning of that sentence?

Thank You.

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense. Are you sure you've typed out the right thing?

Comment: I'm sorry
It was typo :)

Comment: @Kris why did you roll it back to the version that the OP admits has a typo in it?

Comment: @MattЭллен It's a radical change. I rejected the edit, but by then someone passed it. The edit has not improved the understandability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the (corrected) sentence *I have it cut every week* the *have* is a *causative verb* followed by an *object* and a *past participle*. It is used to express the idea of getting someone else to do the cutting rather than doing it yourself. Similar examples of the causative *have* are:

> He has his hair cut every week. (*He gets someone to cut his hair.*)
>
> She had her car repaired. (*She got someone to repair her car.*)
>
> I need to have my house painted. (*I need to get someone to paint my house.*)